# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, запятая в скобках лишняя. Или здесь уточнение?

Чтобы исключить данную проблему в ИЖС, предлагается [2], главным образом, при наличии встроенного НЗ ЭМК в ГПО (,) подключать сигнализаторы загазованности к нормально открытым (НО) ЭМК.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь "главным образом" не вводное словосочетание, а наречное выражение в начале присоединительного оборота.

*Чтобы исключить данную проблему в ИЖС, предлагается, главным образом при наличии встроенного НЗ ЭМК в ГПО, подключать сигнализаторы загазованности к нормально открытым (НО) ЭМК.*

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о том, что "предлагается, главным образом, [сформулированный далее метод]", боюсь, что одной расстановкой запятых ясного смысла не передать. Я бы вставил слово "следующее".
Чтобы исключить данную проблему в ИЖС, предлагается [2], главным образом, **следующее:** при наличии встроенного НЗ ЭМК в ГПО подключать сигнализаторы загазованности к нормально открытым (НО) ЭМК.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы убрала запятую после "главным образом": если стоит запятая под цифрой 2, значит, это  пояснительный оборот, а вводное сочетание в начале оборота не обосабливается, следовательно, запятая в скобках обозначила конец оборота, а внутри него запятой нет.

Если б не было вводного, возможно было бы обойтись без запятых: Чтобы исключить данную проблему в ИЖС, предлагается  при наличии встроенного НЗ ЭМК в ГПО  подключать сигнализаторы загазованности к нормально открытым (НО) ЭМК.

Comment: Я думала о таком варианте, но мне кажется, что здесь "главным образом" относится не к обороту "при наличии встроенного НЗ ЭМК в ГПО", а к тому, что главным образом предлагается.

Comment: Если взять такой вариант, получится:Чтобы исключить данную проблему в ИЖС, предлагается , главным образом, подключать сигнализаторы загазованности к нормально открытым (НО) ЭМК. А что, можно подключать и к ненормально открытым? А вот при наличии... или без него - явная вариативность.Я, конечно,не понимаю инженерного смысла, может, и ошибаюсь.